# Programmatically determine ArcGIS Layer(*.lyr) file version

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap

I've been through IStorage, Microsoft Compound File Spec, ArcObjects deserialization etc. trying to detect the .lyr file version.

Using ArcObjects, I can get at the Layer properties, data source, extent, etc, but the documentVersion property of the LayerFileClass always reports back 'esriArcGISVersion10' on 9.3 Layer files.

```java
ILayerFile l = new LayerFileClass();
l.Open(fileName);
LayerFileClass t = (LayerFileClass)l;
string version = t.DocumentVersion.ToString();
```

Any help is appreciated.

Note [this crusty forum post](http://forums.esri.com/thread.asp?c=93&f=1730&t=237097) from 2007.

Comment: Do you get different results in .NET vs java?

Comment: Did you try using MemoryBlobStreamClass instead of LayerFileClass?  Open the lyr file with IMemoryBlobStream.LoadFromFile, then cast to IDocumentVersion.

Comment: RE comment 2: I just tried -- I get esriArcGISVersion10 for 8.3, 9/9.1, 9.2 and 9.3 layer files. RE comment 1: Java....? What's that? ;)  Thanks for your help. I don't think it's possible.

Comment: It may be helpful if we understood why you're trying to detect the .lyr file version?

Comment: Because I want to know what the version is.

Comment: You tagged your question with `arcobjectsjava` which indicates you are using arcobjects with Java.  Is this not the case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once a layer file is loaded, it is the current version as opening upgrades it.  The DocumentVersion property exists solely to set a version for save back to a prior version with the LayerFile class.

The actual document version is not written to a layer file.  The only version information written is the internal persistence version of the object.  This information can be extracted via structured storage but you'd need a lookup of this version number for every possible layer type (and you'd also need to extract the layer type guid to even tell the layer type).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm a little lost by it.  What is meant by 'every possible layer type' -- as far as I can tell there are five possible versions: 8.3, 9/9.1, 9.2, 9.3 and 10.

Comment: By layer types I mean FeatureLayer, RasterLayer, GroupLayer etc.